# intellij error when importing scala breeze

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-breeze

I am trying to import the scala breeze project that I have downloaded from github with intellij.

I import it as sbt project and then I get the following error:

```
14:16:48 SBT project import
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does no... (show balloon)
14:16:51 Resolver Indexer: Repository is absent or invalid: /Users/donbeo/.m2/repository
```

If I use sbt from console I am able to build and test it correctly

EDIT:

I manually made the folder

```
lucas-MacBook-Pro:breeze donbeo$ mkdir /Users/donbeo/.m2/
lucas-MacBook-Pro:breeze donbeo$ mkdir /Users/donbeo/.m2/repository
```

when I build from intellij I still receive and error:

```
01:47:28 SBT project import
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
         [warn] Credentials file /Users/donbeo/.ivy2/.credentials does no... (show balloon)
01:49:00 Compilation completed with 31 errors and 0 warnings in 5s 723ms
01:49:10 Compilation completed with 31 errors and 0 warnings in 1s 852ms
01:52:31 Compilation completed with 31 errors and 0 warnings in 1s 465ms


/Users/donbeo/Documents/scala_code/breeze/macros/src/test/scala/breeze/macros/arityizeTest.scala
Error:(13, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(5)
     ^
Error:(14, 83) not found: value x
    class Foo[@arityize.replicate T](@arityize.replicate x:  T @arityize.relative(x)) {
                                                                                  ^
Error:(14, 83) recursive value x needs type
    class Foo[@arityize.replicate T](@arityize.replicate x:  T @arityize.relative(x)) {
                                                                                  ^
Error:(18, 19) not found: type Foo2
    val foo = new Foo2[Int, String](x1=3, x2 = "Foo")
                  ^
Error:(18, 37) not found: value x1
    val foo = new Foo2[Int, String](x1=3, x2 = "Foo")
                                    ^
Error:(18, 43) not found: value x2
    val foo = new Foo2[Int, String](x1=3, x2 = "Foo")
                                          ^
Error:(24, 81) recursive value x needs type
    def foo[@arityize.replicate T](@arityize.replicate x:  T @arityize.relative(x)) = (x: @arityize.relative(foo))
                                                                                ^
Error:(24, 110) recursive method foo needs result type
    def foo[@arityize.replicate T](@arityize.replicate x:  T @arityize.relative(x)) = (x: @arityize.relative(foo))
                                                                                                             ^
Error:(23, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(5)
     ^
Error:(26, 12) not found: value foo2
    assert(foo2(1, 2) === 2)
           ^
Error:(35, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(10)
     ^
Error:(37, 121) recursive value t needs type
      def apply(workSize1: Int = 1, workSize2: Int = 1, workSize3: Int = 1)(@arityize.replicate t: T @arityize.relative(t)):Unit = {
                                                                                                                        ^
Error:(44, 9) not found: type CuKernel2
    new CuKernel2[Int, String](1, Array()).apply()(1, "2")
        ^
Error:(48, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(2)
     ^
Error:(50, 82) recursive value t needs type
      def apply(workSize1: Int = 1)(@arityize.replicate t:  T @arityize.relative(t)):Unit = {
                                                                                 ^
Error:(56, 151) recursive method getKernel needs result type
    def getKernel[@arityize.replicate T](name: String, blockDims: Array[Int] = Array(32, 1, 1)): (CuKernel[T @arityize.replicate ] @arityize.relative(getKernel)) = {
                                                                                                                                                      ^
Error:(55, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(2)
     ^
Error:(57, 64) missing arguments for method getKernel;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
      new (CuKernel[T @arityize.replicate ] @arityize.relative(getKernel))(name, blockDims)
                                                               ^
Error:(68, 40) not found: type Tuple
    implicit def tuple[V] : LiteralRow[Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple),V] = new LiteralRow[Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple),V] {
                                       ^
Error:(68, 85) recursive method tuple needs result type
    implicit def tuple[V] : LiteralRow[Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple),V] = new LiteralRow[Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple),V] {
                                                                                    ^
Error:(67, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(6)
     ^
Error:(68, 112) not found: type Tuple
    implicit def tuple[V] : LiteralRow[Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple),V] = new LiteralRow[Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple),V] {
                                                                                                               ^
Error:(69, 28) not found: type Tuple
      def foreach[X](tup : Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple), fn : ((Int,V) => X)) = {
                           ^
Error:(75, 79) not found: value __order__
      def length(tup : Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple)) = __order__
                                                                              ^
Error:(75, 24) not found: type Tuple
      def length(tup : Tuple[V @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tuple)) = __order__
                       ^
Error:(80, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(22)
     ^
Error:(81, 42) not found: type Tuple
    case class TupleToDenseVector(tuple: Tuple[Any @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(TupleToDenseVector))
                                         ^
Error:(81, 89) illegal cyclic reference involving object TupleToDenseVector
    case class TupleToDenseVector(tuple: Tuple[Any @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(TupleToDenseVector))
                                                                                        ^
Error:(85, 50) recursive method tupleToDenseVector needs result type
      new (TupleToDenseVector @arityize.relative(tupleToDenseVector)) (tuple)
                                                 ^
Error:(84, 46) not found: type Tuple
    implicit def tupleToDenseVector(  tuple: Tuple[Any @arityize.repeat] @arityize.relative(tupleToDenseVector)  ) = {
                                             ^
Error:(83, 6) too many arguments for constructor arityize: ()breeze.macros.arityize
    @arityize(22)
     ^
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is an sbt problem. Have you tried `mkdir /Users/donbeo/.m2/repository` ?

Comment: does it compile from the command line (`sbt compile`)?

Comment: yes sbt compile works well

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new version of intelliJ and had this same problem. It turns out I did not enable the maven plugin. If you go to plugins and enable them (Maven Integration and Maven Integration Extension), it should index everything properly.
[image: Intellij plugins window]